# Oracle EPM Hyperion 11.2 - Java API Class LoadExtractOM Method loadData not working

Tags: java, oracle, api, hyperion

I have developed 3 web services ( jax-rs) using the Hyperion Java API's in 11.1.2.4
i. Logon
ii. Get Metadata
iii. Load data into HFM
All work in 11.1.2.4 environment. When testing them in the 11.2 environment I came across an issue with the the Standard Method loadData in the LoadExtractOM. In 11.1.2.4 my web service was able to scan and load the file into HFM and then return the log file of the errors. In 11.2 this is not the case. The  LoadExtractOM.loadData only returns a log file with the start and end date of the scan and no errors. When I do a manual scan of the file in HFM the full scan log is returned. There's no HFMException messages and the load file is copied into the correct folder having been processed. Anybody have any ideas what the issue could be.

I checked the xfm application log xfm.odl.XXXXXXFM-1 and there seems to be an error in the parser

```
[2020-06-18T14:41:09.851832+00:00] [XFM] [ERROR:1] [EPMHFM-00000] [XFM] [ecid: 0000NB7s5pr3JByr04zW6F1UurLA000009] [File: c:\nsh00dph_build_view\hfm\source\session\xfmdata\cxfmdatafileparser.cpp] [Line: 233] [userId: ] [Msg arguments: ] [appName: XXXXXXFM] [pid: 7132] [tid: 9908] [host: WIN-V6SE6NGK443] [nwaddr: [fe80::1933:e8b7:9c66:f8e0%5]:0;[fe80::1851:3b40:ff89:4a96%6]:0;[fe80::3d62:44ba:7543:5157%2]:0;[2a04:3541:1000:500:1933:e8b7:9c66:f8e0]:0;169.254.248.224:0;94.237.48.41:0;10.2.2.89:0;] [errorCode: 0] [srcException: XfmExc] [errType: 1] [dbUpdate: 1] [11.2.1.0.000.5410]
```

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is running on the same system as Hyperion. This caused an issue for the web services as they were setting different System Environments for EPM_ORACLE_HOME and EPM_ORACLE_INSTANCE than the Hyperion system. Changed the System Environments in the Web Services and is all working now